# Store value in a directive for later use

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to save an object in a `ngRepeat` so that I can use that object in its children, like shown in this code:

```
<div ng-repeat="bar in foo.bar> 
    <div ng-repeat="qux in baz.qux" myvalue="{'item1':foo.var1, 'item2':qux.var2}">
        <div ng-click="myFirstFunction(myvalue)"></div>
        <div ng-click="mySecondFunction(myvalue)"></div>
    </div 
</div
```

The object I want to generate and then use is rather large and I'd rather not define it repeatedly for each `ngClick` directive.

I considered saving it into a scope variable but the object will change for each iteration of the `ngRepeat`.

Is there a directive or an other way that I can use to store this value for later use?

Comment: User services to persist data. Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/16709421/1182982

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the repetition of what is probably a long variable definition, you can use the [`ngInit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) directive, whose content will be executed each time a corresponding element is created.

```
<div ng-repeat="bar in foo.bar> 
    <div
        ng-repeat="qux in baz.qux"
        ng-init="myValue = {'item1':foo.var1, 'item2':qux.var2 }"
    >
        <div ng-click="myFirstFunction(myValue)"></div>
        <div ng-click="mySecondFunction(myValue)"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, a complex code in a template is rarely a good idea. Contemplate moving your logic inside a controller, as advised by the documentation:

> The only appropriate use of `ngInit` is for aliasing special properties of `ngRepeat`, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use [controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) rather than `ngInit` to initialize values on a scope.

Comment: Moving to a controller was the first thing I attempted, however, myValue will change in each iteration of ng-repeat. In a asp.net repeater object, saving variables per iteration isnt straight forward and I assumed ng-repeat would behave similier. I am open to methods to move this to the controller if you have any idea.

Comment: I guess that create a controller specifically for the most nested `<div>`, and initialise your value in it, is an unnecessary overhead, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the naive thing here and it'll work:

```
<div ng-repeat="bar in foo.bar> 
    <div ng-repeat="qux in baz.qux">
        <div ng-click="myFirstFunction(foo, quz)"></div>
        <div ng-click="mySecondFunction(foo, quz)"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular will know the scope of the repeat when you click.

Comment: thats what Im trying to avoid because Im passing like 8 variables several nested ng-repeats, and there are about 7 ng-clicks within each iteration. Passing this many variables for every ng-click makes it look very messy and violates DRY. This is my fallback, but Im hoping there is a better way.

Comment: I see, I understand now. Let me think about that.

Comment: @MichaelTaylor3D, can you just pass foo and quz (ie only two params). I assume you don't have too deep a nest of loops?

Comment: I have a total of 8 nested loops generating every permutation 8 of arrays.

Answer (score -1):

You could store it in local storage using ng-storage.
https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

This would allow you to store it, then use it anywhere in the application.

Comment: My understanding is that ng-repeat pre-renders in a single pass so saving it outside of the directive will only push the last value generated. At least thats what happens in a asp.net repeater object. Otherwise I would just save the variable to the scope.

Answer (score -1):

cookies, you also have ng-cookies 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies

try this out! or cookieStorage