# Logic in the controller that isn't assigned directly to the scope should be fulfilled else where before it gets to the controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

```
 $scope.listValueChanged = function (name) {
 listId = [];
 $scope.listType= name;
 };

 if ($scope.contacts &&   $scope.contacts.length > 0) {
       var gsSelectedContacts =$scope.contacts;
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.contacts.length; i++) {
         contactIds.push(gsSelectedContacts[i].id);
       }
 }
```

for the above code I got review comments from my superior like below **Logic in the controller that isn't assigned directly to the scope should be fulfilled elsewhere before it gets to the controller, then applied to the `$scope`**.
I am using this method at one place only. Do, i really need to move this logic to services?

Comment: its not clear what you want to do

Comment: Your code looks like [spaghetti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code). You would be wise to follow the advice of your superior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it depends on whats the use case here . If you are going to reuse something its better to create a `service` for that but if you are not going to reuse or the code is not enough to be used as a service then you should avoid using service . `Service` are meant to make your code more organized and  give better usability so it depends on whats you're requirement really is.

[details on where to use service can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709421/why-use-services-in-angular)

Comment: Link shared @BOSS very useful

Comment: @MurthyM  :)  go through this will help you take better designing decision

Answer (score 0):

Try to do following changes and move commented logic to service

create getter and setter in service for listType

**Js code**

```
  $scope.listType = '';
  $scope.listValueChanged = function(name) {
    listId = [];
    $scope.listType = name;
  };

  if ($scope.contacts && $scope.contacts.length > 0) {
    var contactIds = [];
    var gsSelectedContacts = $scope.contacts;
    //
    // this logic you can keep in service
    //
    $scope.contacts.map(function(contact) {
      contactIds.push(contact);
    });
  }
```

Hope this will help you